# C# - Merging List of Objects into One Object

Tags: c#

I get passed a list of small objects:

```
var smalls = new List<Small>();
smalls.AddRange( new Small[] { new Small{Name = "Aa", Id = 1, Value = "v1"},
                               new Small{Name = "Bb", Id = 1, Value = "v2"},
                               new Small{Name = "Cc", Id = 1, Value = "v3"},
                               new Small{Name = "Dd", Id = 1, Value = "v4"},
                               new Small{Name = "Ee", Id = 1, Value = "v5"},
                               new Small{Name = "Ff", Id = 1, Value = "v6"},
                               new Small{Name = "Gg", Id = 1, Value = "v7"} } );
```

From the above list I would like to populate an object that looks like this:

```
var large = new Large
    {
        Id = 1,
        Aa = "v1",
        Bb = "v2",
        Cc = "v3",
        Dd = "v4",
        Ee = "v5",
        Ff = "v6",
        Gg = "v7"
    }
```

The current code relies on the order of the list to populate the Large object however this does not feel secure enough and am looking for a more reliable way to map the list into the object.

Current code:

```
Large large = new Large
{
    Id = smalls[0].Id,
    Aa = smalls[0].Value,
    Bb = smalls[1].Value,
    Cc = smalls[2].Value,
    Dd = smalls[3].Value,
    Ee = smalls[4].Value,
    Ff = smalls[5].Value,
    Gg = smalls[6].Value
}
```

So I am looking to eliminate the assumption that they are in the correct order and populate the new fields based off of the Name string in the Small object into the corresponding field in the Large object.

Thanks for any input!!

Comment: Are you only concerned about the order or is there a name integrity consideration?

Comment: Great question, I am only concerned about the order issue now. The data in the Name field of the Small objects will always match a corresponding field name in the Large object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I am looking to eliminate the assumption that they are in the correct order

Something like this perhaps?:

```
Aa = smalls.Single(s => s.Name == "Aa").Value
```

This at least still relies on the assumption that the record will be there at all, though it doesn't care about the order of the records.  If you want to drop that assumption as well, you can add some error checking.  Something like this perhaps:

```
Aa = smalls.Any(s => s.Name == "Aa") ? smalls.First(s => s.Name == "Aa") : string.Empty
```

It's not the most efficient thing in the world, but at least remains on one line as in your current usage.  Separating into multiple lines will make it longer, but potentially more performant (if performance is even an issue... in the very small example provided it really isn't).

Those multiple lines could potentially then be re-factored into a custom extension method to put it back onto a single line?  The sky's the limit, really.

Answer (score 3):

You can group values by `Id`, and make a few methods to extract values based on the `Name` field:

```
private static string GetValueByName(IDictionary<string,string> data, string name) {
    string res;
    return data.TryGetValue(name, out res) ? res : null;
}
private static Large MakeFromAttributes(IEnumerable<Small> data, int id) {
    var dictByName = data.ToDictionary(s => s.Name, s => s.Value);
    return new Large {
        Id = id
    ,   Aa = GetValueByName(dictByName, "Aa")
    ,   Bb = GetValueByName(dictByName, "Bb")
    ,   Cc = GetValueByName(dictByName, "Cc")
    ,   Dd = GetValueByName(dictByName, "Dd")
    ,   Ee = GetValueByName(dictByName, "Ee")
    ,   Ff = GetValueByName(dictByName, "Ff")
    ,   Gg = GetValueByName(dictByName, "Gg")
    };
}
```

With these helper methods you can construct a LINQ query as follows:

```
var largeList = smalls
    .GroupBy(s => s.Id)
    .Select(g => MakeFromAttributes(g, g.Key))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

A `Dictionary(TKey, TValue)` may be a more appropriate data structure for the use case since the Keys can be dynamic and any solution going from `IEnumerable(Small)` to `Large` will need to make assumptions on the composition of the collection or the aggregate object.

A simple dynamic solution is to use reflection, but this will have more overhead compared to the static lookup already proposed.

```
public static Large CreateLargeFromSmalls(int id, IEnumerable<Small> smalls)
{
    var largeType = typeof(Large);
    var large = new Large { Id = id };

    foreach (var small in smalls)
    {
        var prop = largeType.GetProperty(small.Name);
        if (prop != null)
        {
            prop.SetValue(large, small.Value);
        }
    }

    return large;
}
```

Assumptions

- The `Name` of a `Small` will exactly match the corresponding `Large` property.
- The `Name` of a `Small` is not unique and order of iteration matters.
- If the property corresponding to the `Name` of a `Small` does not existing in the `Large` then it is not mapped.

Pros

- Contract changes to `Large` do not affect the mapping logic.

Cons

- Reflection overhead

Example:

```
var smalls = new List<Small>
{
    new Small{Name = "Aa", Id = 1, Value = "v1"},
    new Small{Name = "Bb", Id = 1, Value = "v2"},
    new Small{Name = "Cc", Id = 1, Value = "v3"},
    new Small{Name = "Dd", Id = 1, Value = "v4"},
    new Small{Name = "Ee", Id = 1, Value = "v5"},
    new Small{Name = "Ff", Id = 1, Value = "v6"},
    new Small{Name = "Gg", Id = 1, Value = "v7"}
};

var bigs =
    smalls
        .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
        .Select(g => CreateLargeFromSmalls(g.Key, g))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I had the same idea!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can use reflection to set all properties in the `Large` class without having to worry about order of `Small` collection:

```
Large large = new Large();
foreach (var propertyInfo in large.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var sm = smalls.FirstOrDefault(small => string.Equals(small.Name, propertyInfo.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    if (sm != null)
        propertyInfo.SetValue(large, Convert.ChangeType(sm.Value, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
}
```

Important: Please note that for this solution to work, all properties of `Large` that need to be updated **MUST** be marked with getters and setters. eg. `public string Aa { get; set; }`

We first get all properties of `Large` by using `large.GetType().GetProperties()` which gets all properties. Then we compare the names with the `.Name` property in the `Small` class collection and if we find a match then we set the value of the property. You can read more about reflection [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx).

Screenshot of `Large` after trying it out:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can group your list of `Small`'s, then set `Id` as the `Key` of the group and other properties using reflection, will look like this

```
var large = smalls.GroupBy(small => small.Id)
    .Select(group =>
    {
        var result = new Large();
        result.Id = group.Key;
        var largeType = result.GetType();
        foreach (var small in group)
        {
                largeType.GetProperty(small.Name).SetValue(result, small.Value);
        }
        return result;
    }).First();
```